# Can we have a migration path → superuser, graphicdesign, and video, please?

Tags: feature-request, photoshop, migration, video

A lot of "how do I use photoshop" questions are off-topic here, as they are not really related to photography per se. (See site definition.) On Serverfault, when I vote to close a question, I see a migration choice for some other relevant sites like Stack Overflow.

It would be useful to have a Superuser migration path — photoshop questions are [on topic there](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/adobe-photoshop), and we sometimes get computer hardware/software questions that aren't really related to photography in any important way.

Discussion on [graphicdesign meta](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83/photoshop-questions) suggests that a lot of questions would be on topic there (although some of the "how do I work my software" stuff may still be better on superuser).

And finally, [Video](https://video.stackexchange.com/) is the destination for video/cinema questions.

Comment: +1. Isn't there a graphic design stack exchange too?

Answer (score 5):

They'd prossibly be better going to [graphic-design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) which is still in beta, but in the meantime, you can flag them for moderator attention if you think they should move, whilst still voting to close as off-topic.

Comment: I looked at the definition for the Graphic Design site (http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1924?phase=definition), and it looks to me from the questions tagged as off-topic that they have the same basic objection we do: the site is about graphic design, not how-to-work-software-which-can-be-used-for-design. But I'll go ask on their meta site and see.

Comment: Oh, someone else did already. Awesome. http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/83/photoshop-questions

Comment: Reading http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/83/photoshop-questions/85#85 there makes me think that Superuser really is the better place for _most_ of the Photoshop questions we get.

Comment: @mattdm but http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/83/photoshop-questions/84#84 implies they'd be more welcomed (and that's one of their mods)

Answer (score 4):

This isn't a bad idea, but we try mightily to avoid migrating to sites that are still in public beta, at least as far as making them official.

I don't oppose some one-offs getting migrated here and there if they are strong fits, but ...

Once we add a site to the "blessed" close / migrate list, that implies the site will be around forever, and if we end up shutting down the site, that would be ... traumatic for those that had their questions migrated there.

Comment: That makes sense. I'll be patient. How about to Superuser now, though? Questions like http://superuser.com/questions/278793/sd-hard-drive-does-it-exist aren't infrequent.

Comment: @matt in the meantime flag for moderator attention with the title of the site you wish to migrate to. I support strongly matching one-offs.

Answer (score 3):

Also, Video & Film, if it gets out of beta: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2797/video-and-film-production

Comment: http://avp.stackexchange.com/ is now live :)

Answer (score 1):

Might also be worth having a path to the [UI design](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) site too

Comment: Interesting. Can you give an example of a question that was asked here that would have been better there?

Comment: Not *yet*. Some have come close, but were better suited to graphic-design

Comment: I think we should only have "simple" migration paths for the most common cases (photoshop->superuser, graphic design, and video, I think), and for the more rare ones, flag for moderator attention.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO this would also need SuperUser for general computer questions (recovering files from SD card, trouble with USB/Wifi connection, etc...)