# Can we remove vague duplicated questions

Tags: discussion

I have seen a few vague questions such as ['Which Program is good for modifying pictures'](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/17798/which-program-is-good-for-modifying-pictures)

Now these have already been asked and answered, however without specifically asking about a certain criteria I feel that they are pointless and lead to discussion.

A more appropriate question may be, I want to be able to crop my images and reduce red eye, what software will do this for me effectively within my budget of XX.

There is too much personal opinion in the answers that categorically will all be correct.

We all have our own preferences as to which brand of camera we use, which software we use, or how our workflow differs from others.

Most of these questions I have noticed are coming from new Stack exchange users, now there is noting wrong with a new user, but it is clear that they have not searched for the answer properly or read policy on questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The community *can* remove such questions without effort from a moderator. Vote to close the question (which requires rep 3000) and a few days after the question is closed, vote to delete (10000 rep).

It's best *not* to delete questions closed as duplicates, though, since the duplicates serve as pointers to the "canonical" question for future searchers who might think to phrase the question in the second way.

It's also nice to post some comment explaining how the question could be improved before voting to close (such votes can't be rescinded). A downvote is another option, although completely new users to stack exchange might take that too harshly and it's better to take it easy at first. (If the person is coming from Stack Overflow, they should know better!)

If the question shows some potential or at least moderate investment from the person asking, consider both providing a helpful answer *and* commenting to ask for clarification.

If the question is downright rude, or is spam or trolling, flagging is totally the way to go.

And until we have a [migration path to likely targets for misplaced questions](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/690/can-we-have-a-migration-path-superuser-graphicdesign-and-avp-please), those need to be flagged too.

Comment: I'm going to poke this question with a link from [U&L.SE](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3510/clean-up-question-on-this-qa?cb=1).

Answer (score 2):

I have a growing backlog of questions that need to be evaluated for merger and deleted. I don't have a whole lot of time during the week these days, so I tend to put those off until the weekend. I DO check every flag for questions that have likely duplicates and are candidates for merger, but I prefer not to take immediate action on them. I think each of those questions need to be properly evaluated to determine if they are indeed duplicates and safe to merge, or whether some of them have distinctions that merit their own existence.