# How to vote to close an off topic question?

Tags: support

When I try to vote to close a question as being off topic, I can't because I must now choose a SE site that would be more appropriate. Unfortunately, the only option given is to migrate the question to Photo.stack exchange.com which is the site I think the question does NOT belong to. As far as I can tell, there is no way to select another SE site, even those I am a part of.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I understand what you're seeing - I see:

Close >

- off-topic because...

And then there are the four options to pick as to why it's off topic.

To improve the options for migrations to other sites, we need to prove there is sufficient volume to justify the need, and these are better flagged for moderator attention **in addition to** being voted to close.

Answer (score 1):

See also [Can we have a migration path → superuser, graphicdesign, and video, please?](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/690/can-we-have-a-migration-path-superuser-graphicdesign-and-avp-please). There have always been only a limited number of target sites, and apparently this is by design.

If a question really belongs on another site, vote to close with a custom off-topic note, and then flag for moderator attention -- moderators can migrate to anywhere.

Comment: I believe moderators can migrate to any site in the entire network, meta sites included. If you guys can't see the right site to migrate to, you can just flag it for moderator attention with the site you think is right, and we should be able to do it.