# When flagging a question as off-topic, is there a way to suggest another SE site

Tags: feature-request, off-topic, flagging

Currently if I flag a question as "better suited for another SE site", the only suggestion is this "meta". How can I suggest "GraphicDesign" (for PS/Gimp questions) or SuperUser (for general computer questions, such as recovering files). Or can these be added by the Powers That Be?

Comment: FWIW I see the same thing. I typically close these and also flag or mod intervention citing a xfer to another stack.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we have a migration path → superuser, graphicdesign, and video, please?](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/690/can-we-have-a-migration-path-%e2%86%92-superuser-graphicdesign-and-video-please)

Answer (score 3):

> How can I suggest "GraphicDesign" (for PS/Gimp questions) or SuperUser (for general computer questions, such as recovering files).

Flag for moderator attention.

> Or can these be added by the Powers That Be?

They can add migration targets, but they won't unless there is a pattern of migration between the two sites. For further reading, [start here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261196/164922).

Answer (score -1):

I do not know if this is part of photo.SE config or it depend of reputation but in unix.SE I see

*"Closing -> Other (add a comment explaining what is wrong)"*

Maybe me and you we do not have enough reputation to see this in flagging menu.

Based on the comment and reputation of Hueco seems like photo.SE do not have such option configured. And I agree it can be helpful in some cases.

EDIT: Currently I see in photo.SE the same like unix.SE (and already use it)